# LaTeX Error: File `scrpage2.sty' not found

Tags: errors

Can someone explain how to solve this problem: LaTeX Error: File `scrpage2.sty' not found? I read all the answers but didn't understand what to do. Today I install miktex 2.9 and winedt 10.3.

Comment: scrpage2.sty is obsolete, and is moved. Read the documentation. Use ` scrlayer-scrpage` instead, see [message at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrpage2) from the author.

Comment: See also https://komascript.de/faq_scrpage2_en (English) and https://komascript.de/faq_scrpage2 (German).

Answer (score 64):

The author has declared the package `scrpage2` obsolete. It is no longer included in TeX live and MikTeX. The package is still available on CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/scrpage2, https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script-obsolete), but it would have to be installed manually from the `.dtx` source. See also https://komascript.de/faq_scrpage2_en.

Users are advised to switch to the successor package `scrlayer-scrpage`. If you have

```
\usepackage[<options>]{scrpage2}
```

in your preamble, replace it with

```
\usepackage[<options>]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

Apparently all commands and options of `scrpage2` are also recognised by `scrlayer-scrpage`, so a switch should be possible. But users are strongly encouraged to double check the results and consult the `.log` file as well as the manual for hints about deprecated, obsolete or otherwise outdated commands.

(Just to be clear, `scrlayer-scrpage` is part of the regular KOMA-Script bundle and can be installed as the package `koma-script` in both MiKTeX and TeX live if it isn't installed already.)

If some code/package beyond your control loads `scrpage2`, contact the author and look into alternatives (`scrpage2` has been up for deprecation for quite a while [about six years; it has thrown warnings for at least two years according to https://komascript.de/faq_scrpage2_en], so if the code author hasn't reacted until now, that suggests they might not follow the development of their code that closely any more). If you *must* use external code that uses `scrpage2`, you can try the workaround suggested at https://komascript.de/faq_scrpage2_en:

Add

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplacePackage{scrpage2}{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

to your preamble before the `\documentclass` line. That will load `scrlayer-scrpage` when any code requests `scrpage2`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally it works!

Comment: @Silva I'm glad it works for you. But don't just make the changes, actively look at the `.log` files and the documentation to make sure you are not using outdated commands/options. If this is not code you wrote yourself, tell the author about the deprecation and be wary of its overall quality.

Comment: Thank you! This worked seamlessly.

Comment: +1: I ran into the exact same problem today!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone (like me) is using Overleaf and gets the scrpage2.sty error, you can choose to work on your document with a previous version of TeXLive that still supports the obsolete package (see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_packages_do_you_support%3F)).

On the long run this will create problems to your doc, but it works for me when need a quick fix to a non-important file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mensch!

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a comment to the first reply, but I don't have enough "reputation" yet. (just linked my account with tex.stackexchange), but I think it's important to note.
I use documentclass `scrreprt` and the solution by moewe (replacing `scrpage2` with `scrlayer-scrpage`) worked for me, although I got new errors and had to include definitions for the layout of `\section` etc. to fix them:

```
\begin{document}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

`\sffamily` makes text sans-serif, `\bfseries` makes it bold.

This might help others struggling with this unexpected deprecation of an otherwise stable system ....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!