# How can I install scrpage2?

Tags: miktex, koma-script, scrpage2, portable

I have a very old LaTeX project with a pile of custom templates I glued together in a few dozens of hours work. It uses `scrpage2`.

Unfortunately, I do not have my old MikTex Portable installation any more, so I need to do a fresh install -- but of course, it cannot find `scrpage2`!

When I replace it with its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`, I get tons of LaTeX errors, so I think it would be easier to install the obsolete package by hand.

But how can I do that? Where can I get it from, for starters? I am using MikTeX Portable on Windows.

Comment: I doubt that it is so difficult to adapt your templates - don't look at the number of errors, that is not relevant, look at the first one.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541766/35864 my answer mentions in passing how you could get `scrpage2`: You'd have to download it from CTAN, compile the `.dtx` to the required `.sty` and install it manually. More help on that is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864. I have only very faint ideas about KOMA-Script, but from what I heard it should be possible to switch from `scrpage2` to `scrlayer-scrpage` without too much effort. (So definitely do what Ulrike suggests.)

Comment: I still have my old MikTeX and the old `scrpage2.sty`, can I just copy it to the new installation? The problem with adapting is that I not only haven't touched the project for about ten years now, I haven't touched LaTeX for about ten years now! I cannot even understand my own template any more...

Comment: @Kurtibert Just copy the old scrpage2 to the folder where you have your project files and compile. If you have different project in different folders, you may copy the file to you local tex root directory (for example c:\texmf-local), refresh the file name database (run texhash or use miktex cosole menu), and then compile.

Comment: You can copy files to your folder or to a local texmf. But mixing old and new styles has its problems too. You could also attach the old texmf tree as a local root and use only the old styles. But if you get errors with these old styles you probably won't be able to ask for help.