# Why are the URL's not displayed when I run the pdf?

Tags: urls, compilation-error

I can't find the mistake here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
pointlessnumbers, 
%draft,
parskip=half,
automark
    ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\cdot}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{x}
\author{x}
\date{x}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\subsection{Quellen}
Abbildung $\ref{fig:7}$: $\url{de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelspaltexperiment}$, 13.3.22 13:29Uhr

Abbildung $\ref{fig:8}$: $\url{www.schule-bw.de/faecher-und-schularten/mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche-faecher/physik/unterrichtsmaterialien/wellen/interferenz/mehrfachspalte.html}$, 13.3.22 13:33Uhr

Abbildung $\ref{fig:8}$: $\url{www.google.com/search?q=dreifachspalt&sxsrf=APq-WBv9xT2QQ0FdNDcDKjurBfK31n_9mA:1647174717822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ7cD_i8P2AhVkSfEDHc4dCIoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung%20NRW,03%3A%$20Optisches%20Gitter}$

Abbildung $\ref{fig:10}$: Giancoli Physik, Pearson
Abbildung $\ref{fig:11}$: Giancoli Physik, Pearson
Abbildung $\ref{fig:13}$: $\url{de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beugung_(Physik)}[![enter image description here][1]][1]$, 16.3.22, 11:07 Uhr
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As said yesterday: Don't warp them in math mode!

Comment: And just as in your question yesterday: don't use obsolete package which are no longer part of common tex distributions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LaTeX Error: File \`scrpage2.sty' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541766/latex-error-file-scrpage2-sty-not-found)

Comment: @KersouMan I don't think so, that's a different issue. Sure, `scrpage2` is obsolete, but the error here is using `\url` in math mode.

Comment: but i need math mode for all my formulas which are not included in this excerpt, so what can I do?

Comment: Only warp the formulas in math mode, not the URLs!

Comment: how can I end math mode, before the url's, which are required to be displayed at the end of the document? Is there a specific command like \end{math mode} or something like that?

Comment: You don't need to end math mode, you need to not start it with all your `$`

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems:

- as said yesterday, don't use obsolete packages, see [LaTeX Error: File `scrpage2.sty' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541766/latex-error-file-scrpage2-sty-not-found) for more details
- don't use deprecated class options like  `pointlessnumbers`
- don't use obsolete package options like `decimalsymbol=comma`
- you might want to use the `xurl` package so your verrrrrrry long urls don't go off the page margins
- and most importantly: don't wrap your references and urls in math mode. Remove all the incorrect `$` around them
- you shouldn't need the `pdftex` option for color and graphicx
- don't load the same package multiple times

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
%pointlessnumbers, 
%draft,
parskip=half,
%automark
    ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
%\clearscrheadfoot
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[
 %pdftex
]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[
%decimalsymbol=comma
]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\cdot}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{x}
\author{x}
\date{x}

\usepackage{xurl}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
%\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
%\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
%\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\subsection{Quellen}
Abbildung \ref{fig:7}: \url{de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelspaltexperiment}, 13.3.22 13:29Uhr

Abbildung \ref{fig:8}: \url{www.schule-bw.de/faecher-und-schularten/mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche-faecher/physik/unterrichtsmaterialien/wellen/interferenz/mehrfachspalte.html}, 13.3.22 13:33Uhr

Abbildung \ref{fig:8}: \url{www.google.com/search?q=dreifachspalt&sxsrf=APq-WBv9xT2QQ0FdNDcDKjurBfK31n_9mA:1647174717822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ7cD_i8P2AhVkSfEDHc4dCIoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung%20NRW,03%3A%$20Optisches%20Gitter}

Abbildung \ref{fig:10}: Giancoli Physik, Pearson
Abbildung \ref{fig:11}: Giancoli Physik, Pearson
Abbildung \ref{fig:13}: \url{de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beugung_(Physik)}, 16.3.22, 11:07 Uhr
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot! Right now, the URL's are being displayed, but they can't be opened, once I click on them in the pdf. Also, the text of this particular URL "Abbildung $\ref{fig:8}$: \url{www.google.com/search?...}" especially this part is making trouble: "w&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung%20NRW,03%3A%$20Optisches%20Gitter}" can not be displayed in 1 link, but its divided into 3 pieces which one can click on separately, which I don't know how to fix, unfortunately

Comment: @chickenoncrack They work fine for me. Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: the built in texmaker pdf viewer on macOS

Comment: Try with adobe reader. Some pdf viewer, like mac preview, are trying to be clever and instead of the latex hyperlink, they try to guess the link from the text in the pdf.

Comment: Unrelated to latex: are you sure a link to a google search is a good idea? AFAIK the results are personalised so your readers won't see the same page as you and I doubt it will be stable in the long term. Better link to the source of your image.

Comment: Its linked to the specific website, but because latex seperates the link into 3 pieces, once one clicks on the link, one actually only clicks on the first piece of the link instead of the entire link, which is problematic. I put a \ before the $ & % which are part of the link, but still I can't edit the link referencing to fig:8, starting form the w in: "w&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung

\%20NRW,03\%3A\%$20Optisches%20Gitter}". When I press right key on the directional keys, latex jumps directly from the w to the end of this link, so editing it is impossible after the w.

Comment: The link works fine and is in one piece with the pdf viewer from texstudio. (but still, I wouldn't consider a link to a page of search results a valid source for an image...)

Comment: Addendum: [Don't use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/) ;-)

Comment: @chickenoncrack It's not really the point of the question, but for me your google link does not lead to a single image. It just sends me to a google search with about 40 different pictures. It is not at all clear to me which picture you are referring to. In my book this would definitely not be an appropriate reference. I completely agree with samcarter that you need to the real source of the image.

Comment: @chickenoncrack The `https://www.schule-bw.de/faecher-und-schularten/mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche-faecher/physik/unterrichtsmaterialien/wellen/interferenz/mehrfachspalte.html` link also doesn't work for me. I did find a website under `https://www.schule-bw.de/faecher-und-schularten/mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche-faecher/physik/unterrichtsmaterialien/wellen/interferenz/mehrfachspalte.htm` (`htm` instead of `html`) that looks like it could be what you want.