# Why is it impossible to click on the entire URL?

Tags: pdf, compiling, texmaker, urls, compilation-error

Its only possible to click on the first piece of the link:
[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\cdot}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{Blockpraktikum 1 \\ GI}
\author{Sandra Suljovic}
\date{Versuchsdurchführung: 07.10.2020 bei Aaron Stahl (Vertretung von John Keppler)}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}
Abbildung $\ref{fig:8}$: \xurl{www.google.com/search?q=dreifachspalt&sxsrf=APq-WBv9xT2QQ0FdNDcDKjurBfK31n_9mA:1647174717822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ7cD_i8P2AhVkSfEDHc4dCIoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2\$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung\%20NRW,03\%3A\%\$20Optisches\%20Gitter}
```

Comment: Please stop ignoring the error messages from your log file. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output. These problems won't magically resolve, you need to fix them instead of posting the same errors in three questions in a row.

Answer (score 6):

Same errors as in your previous two questions:

- as [cabohah noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672989/why-are-the-urls-not-displayed-when-i-run-the-pdf#comment1672370_672991): [Don't use \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}.](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/)
- as said yesterday, don't use obsolete packages, see [LaTeX Error: File `scrpage2.sty' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541766/latex-error-file-scrpage2-sty-not-found) for more details
- don't use deprecated class options like  `pointlessnumbers`
- don't use obsolete package options like `decimalsymbol=comma`
- you might want to use the `xurl` package so your verrrrrrry long urls don't go off the page margins
- don't wrap `\ref{...}` in math mode!
- you shouldn't need the `pdftex` option for color and graphicx
- don't load the same package multiple times

Now two new errors:

- it should be `\url` not `\xurl`. As you can see from the missing link border and wrong font in your screenshot, the incorrect macro means that your link is rendered as text and not as link. Mac Preview.app (and viewers from the same family), which you seem to be using based in the small gray arrow on the right hand side, will guess urls from the text in the pdf and not because they are marked as link in the pdf. They can't cope with line breaks.
- don't escape special characters inside the url. That's why you use the url macro, to be able to use such characters

---

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 
%    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
%    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
%\clearscrheadfoot
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[
%pdftex
]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[
%decimalsymbol=comma
]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\cdot}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{Blockpraktikum 1 \\ GI}
\author{Sandra Suljovic}
\date{Versuchsdurchführung: 07.10.2020 bei Aaron Stahl (Vertretung von John Keppler)}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
%\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
%\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
%\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}
Abbildung \ref{fig:8}: \url{www.google.com/search?q=dreifachspalt&sxsrf=APq-WBv9xT2QQ0FdNDcDKjurBfK31n_9mA:1647174717822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ7cD_i8P2AhVkSfEDHc4dCIoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung%20NRW,03%3A%$20Optisches%20Gitter}
\end{document}
```

[image]